# How to read the data from a JSON which is not having keys in BigQuery?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have the data in this format

`{"OgDKrh1hT6NzBHXsjh7n8yrkrE62":["U2","X1","D1","C3","H2","D3","O3","Q1","A2"],"UxdTolmzq9cAYjPkTX57VAzas2w1":["E3","S1","V2","W1","M1","H3","L3","G2","Y3"]}`

and I want the data in this format

```
id                              details
OgDKrh1hT6NzBHXsjh7n8yrkrE62    U2,X1,D1,C3,H2,D3,O3,Q1,A2
UxdTolmzq9cAYjPkTX57VAzas2w1    E3,S1,V2,W1,M1,H3,L3,G2,Y3
```

Comment: please clarify table's format. what columns and what data types they are!

Comment: Assume that the table is having just one column which is "raw_data" and the data stored in string format.

Comment: sure. see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select 
  arr[offset(0)] as id,
  arr[offset(1)] as details
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(text, r'"[^"]+":\[[^\[]+\]')) kv,
unnest([struct(split(translate(kv, '"[]', ''), ':') as arr)])
```

if to apply above to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '{"OgDKrh1hT6NzBHXsjh7n8yrkrE62":["U2","X1","D1","C3","H2","D3","O3","Q1","A2"],"UxdTolmzq9cAYjPkTX57VAzas2w1":["E3","S1","V2","W1","M1","H3","L3","G2","Y3"]}' text
)
select 
  arr[offset(0)] as id,
  arr[offset(1)] as details
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(text, r'"[^"]+":\[[^\[]+\]')) kv,
unnest([struct(split(translate(kv, '"[]', ''), ':') as arr)])
```

the output is

[image]